# Travis CI how to build debug and release?

Tags: travis-ci

I have a C++ project and sometimes the release and debug code gets out of sync (some code is #ifdef'd out or breaks with diff compiler options).

I'd like Travis-CI to build both debug and release, how can I do it? If it can be done will this also work with the multiple compiler matrix? I.e would it allow me to build debug and release on g++ and clang?

Comment: Use `env` matrix: [example](https://github.com/forexample/hunter-simple/blob/master/.travis.yml)